# Can't pass double quotes JSON to Javascript from Android Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

Scenario:

TLDR; Why can I not pass ("") from Android to JavaScript, only ('') works?

I'm sending a JSON object from Android to JavaScript through:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foo(\"" + bar + "\")");
```

To my knowledge this calls the javascript function foo() passing it the value of bar.

The bar variable is a JSON object for example:

```
 bar = "{'id':'"+barID+"','title':'"+barTitle+"'}";
```

Now on the javascript side the function foo() does the following:

```
function foo(json){
   var completeJsonObject;
   json = json.replace(/'/g, '"');
   completeJsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
}
```

This works perfectly as it replaces the (') with ("") and then the json can be parsed.

However to avoid having to replace I could just format the json on the java side with ("") instead like bellow right?

```
bar = "{\"id\":\""+barID+"\",\"title\":\""+barTitle+"\"}";
```

Well no, as soon as I do that the JavaScript gives me an unexpected token error.

Is there a better way to fix this than with my solution?

Comment: mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foo(\"" + bar + "\")"); is broken by your " in bar, then javascript is confused. Better keep your solution.

Comment: I guess that makes sense yes.